# R: double integrals on a function with matrix output

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the double integrals on a function with matrix output. My code is here:

```
foo <- function(x,t){
  out1 <- sin(x*t)
  out2 <- cos(x*t)
  out <- matrix(c(out1,out2),ncol=2)
  return(out)
}
library(pracma)
quad2d(foo, xa = 0, xb = 1, ya = 0, yb= 10)
```

When I run this code, I receive a message:

> Error in wx %*% Z : non-conformable arguments

I wonder how I can calculate this double integrals? **The 'foo' is just a simple example here; to seperate the 'foo' into two functions is not I want.** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`quad2d`applies Gaussian quadrature internally, but needs the function to be vectorized. Instead, you can apply the quadrature rules explicitly.

Assume the matrix-valued function `foo` is defined as

```
foo <- function(x, t)
            matrix(c(sin(x*t), cos(x*t), x, t), 2, 2)
```

Utilize the Gaussian quadrature rules directly like this:

```
library(pracma)
n <- 32
xa <- 0; xb <- 1; ya <- 0; yb <- 10

cx <- gaussLegendre(n, xa, xb)
x <- cx$x; wx <- cx$w
cy <- gaussLegendre(n, ya, yb)
y <- cy$x; wy <- cy$w

I <- matrix(0, 2, 2)
for (i in 1:n) {
    for (j in 1:n) {
        I <- I + wx[i] * wy[j] * foo(x[i], y[j])
    }
}
I
##          [,1] [,2]
## [1,] 2.925257    5
## [2,] 1.658348   50
```

This may be a bit slower than `quad2d` as there are two `for` loops, but may be sufficient if your function is somewhat well behaved.

Of course, all this can be wrapped into a new integration routine like
`mquad2d(f, xa, xb, ya, yb, n = 32)`.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an elegant way to pass a matrix of functions as the first argument of the function `quad2d`! I don't know that, but I can re-write your code to get the same result:

```
mquad2d <- function(xa, xb, ya, yb){
  fun1 <- function(x,t){
    return(sin(x*t))
  }
  fun2 <- function(x, t){
    return(cos(x*t))
  }
  out1 <- quad2d(fun1, xa, xb, ya, yb)
  out2 <- quad2d(fun2, xa, xb, ya, yb)
  out <- matrix(c(out1,out2),ncol=2)
  return(out)
}
mquad2d(xa = 0, xb = 1, ya = 0, yb= 10)
#output:
#         [,1]     [,2]
#[1,] 2.925257 1.658348
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you! Your solution could solve the problem in my sample code, but could not solve the problem in my real code; as the 'foo' could not be separated as two functions in my real code.